# Snappoints win 8 apps

Tags: html, css, windows-8

I would like to make my different columns snap. Can I divide my snap points, and is there any document ion on snappoints? I only see guidelines.

Found this code tough but how does it work?

```
-ms-scroll-snap-x: mandatory snapInterval(0px,200px);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good starting point here, check out the code sample and scenarios:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/Scrolling-panning-and-6834aaf9/view/SourceCode

Or this pretty in depth blog post with examples:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/12/09/zooming-amp-panning-with-css-in-ie-10.aspx